# meaning of high rate in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I saw this docs (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#hotspots) and it says:

> Avoid high read or write rates to lexicographically close documents,
>   or your application will experience contention errors. This issue is
>   known as hotspotting, and your application can experience hotspotting
>   if it does any of the following:
>
> Creates new documents at a very high rate and allocates its own
>   monotonically increasing IDs.
>
> Cloud Firestore allocates document IDs using a scatter algorithm. You
>   should not encounter hotspotting on writes if you create new documents
>   using automatic document IDs.
>
> Creates new documents at a high rate in a collection with few
>   documents.
>
> Creates new documents with a monotonically increasing field, like a
>   timestamp, at a very high rate.
>
> Deletes documents in a collection at a high rate.
>
> Writes to the database at a very high rate without gradually
>   increasing traffic.

Does a high rate occur when a lot of users create documents at once?
Or is it talking about creating documents by running a for or while(roop) statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does a high rate occur when a lot of users create documents at once? Or is it talking about creating documents by running a for or while(roop) statement?

Either of those can trigger hotspotting in certain cases with a high write rate. More important than where the writes come from is how fast the write come in, how you assign document IDs, and whether or not you're writing monotonically increasing or decreasing fields.

This article goes into more detail on the timestamp case and describes a workaround:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/shard-timestamp

Comment: So is it safe to work as a production use of an online submission form, with around 600 submission / second, using auto-generated document ID?